# How do I get DirectorySearcher to honor my specified SearchScope?

Tags: .net, active-directory, ldap, directoryservices

I have the following C# code in a project:

```
    DirectoryEntry root = new DirectoryEntry(@"LDAP://ad.mydomain.com");
    DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(root);
    ds.DerefAlias = DereferenceAlias.Always;
    ds.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
    ds.Filter = "(|(name=John_Smith)(cn=John_Smith))";
    SearchResultCollection src = ds.FindAll();
```

I'm monitoring LDAP traffic to the AD server with MS Network Monitor and I see this when the search takes place:

```
  Frame: Number = 1417, Captured Frame Length = 404, MediaType = ETHERNET 
+ Ethernet: Etype = Internet IP (IPv4),DestinationAddress:[XXX],SourceAddress:[XXX]
+ Ipv4: Src = XXX, Dest = XXX, Next Protocol = TCP, Packet ID = 9696, Total IP Length = 390
+ Tcp: Flags=...AP..., SrcPort=1521, DstPort=LDAP(389), PayloadLen=350, Seq=3825204841 - 3825205191, Ack=1241404727, Win=16425 (scale factor 0x2) = 65700
- Ldap: Search Request, MessageID: 1, BaseObject: NULL, SearchScope: base Object, SearchAlias: neverDerefAliases
  - Parser: Search Request, MessageID: 1
   + ParserHeader: 
   + MessageID: 1
   + OperationHeader: Search Request, 3(0x3)
   - SearchRequest: BaseDN: NULL, SearchScope: base Object, SearchAlias: neverDerefAliases
    + BaseObject: NULL
    + Scope: base Object
    + Alias: neverDerefAliases
    + SizeLimit: No Limit
    + TimeLimit: 120 seconds
    + TypesOnly: False
    - Filter: (objectclass Present)
     + Operator: Present, 7(0x07)
     - Length: 11
        Length: 11 bytes, LengthOfLength = 0
     + PresentFilter: objectclass Present
    - Attributes: ( subschemaSubentry )( dsServiceName )( namingContexts )( defaultNamingContext )( schemaNamingContext )( configurationNamingContext )( rootDomainNamingContext )( supportedControl )( supportedLDAPVersion )( supportedLDAPPolicies )( supportedSASLMec
     + AttributeSelectionHeader: 
     + Attribute: subschemaSubentry
     + Attribute: dsServiceName
     + Attribute: namingContexts
     + Attribute: defaultNamingContext
     + Attribute: schemaNamingContext
     + Attribute: configurationNamingContext
     + Attribute: rootDomainNamingContext
     + Attribute: supportedControl
     + Attribute: supportedLDAPVersion
     + Attribute: supportedLDAPPolicies
     + Attribute: supportedSASLMechanisms
     + Attribute: dnsHostName
     + Attribute: ldapServiceName
     + Attribute: serverName
     + Attribute: supportedCapabilities
```

Neither the search scope or filter I requested appear to be being used in the query. I tried using Softerra LDAP Administrator to perform a root search on "John_Smith" and network monitor shows what appears to be a perfectly good LDAP query, with filter and search scope intact.

What am I missing?

Comment: Silly question: Are you sure you are looking at the right ethernet frame? Maybe the frame you have is part of an initialization/negotiation sequence happening before the actual query?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's the right frame. I only see one "LDAP:Search Request, MessageID: 1, BaseObject: NULL, SearchScope: base Object, SearchAlias: neverDerefAliases" and one "LDAP:Search Result Entry, MessageID: 1". The search result is NULL.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I do it:

```
searcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(|(cn=John_Smith)(sAMAccountName=John_Smith)))";
```

An awesome site for everything AD is this one that I use.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/everythingInAD.aspx

Comment: +1 I'm currently developing a block of our framework that dialogs with AD using this precise article! It's awesome what it contains as information! Very good reference!

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I get no results and the LDAP packet appears to still have no filter and scope = base object. Even when I copy-paste the exact filter being used by the Softerra tool I get no results and no apparent filter being passed to the server.

Comment: This sounds like a stupid question, but are you absolutely sure that John_Smith is the 'sAMAccountname'?

Comment: Also, are you sure you don't need to set your username and pasword properties for your Directory Entry?

Comment: Well, it's a different name that I'm searching for, but it's definitely a valid account name in AD. I'm able to find it via the WinNT provider and the Softerra tool.

Comment: It doesn't seem to make any difference if I pass credentials or not.

Comment: I've never used the MS Network Monitor before, but perhaps the filter isn't being shown because you're not actually getting the directory entry.  Does ds.FindAll() return null?

Comment: I get a SearchResultCollection with Count = 0 no matter what I try. I have been able to get what I need with a combination of System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement and direct LDAP queries, but I'm at a loss as to why my simple query above isn't working. I'm sure I'm missing something head-slappingly simple...

Comment: The only explanation I can come up with is either your LDAP connection is incorrect or the username you're searching for is incorrect...but neither of those seems to be the case, so I'm at a loss here.

Answer (score 0):

So the request that is being sent is a query of the capabilities of the ldap server (location of the schema, supported ldap version, etc).  The ldap/AD server can respond with the information requested or require authentication.  You can take care of that step (bind) by supplying credentials when you bind to the root entry.  After the SearchResultsDone message is received for the capabilities query, the directory searcher (actually the underlying ldap class) will send a search request asking for the information that you requested.